# Diagramming tool for this type of diagram?

Tags: diagram, uml, design, component-diagram

I am looking for an app to draw the kind of diagram in the picture which I don't know how to name it.
[image]

I know I can do it with any general diagraming tool but I want the layout to be the more automatc possible. I like Plantuml but I don't know if there is such class of diagram in that.

It can be android Linux or online.

Comment: Maybe https://draw.io